# What does a semicolon ";" do in a Uri string?

Tags: c#, uri

I saw a line in C# codes:

```
Image = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("/MyProgramName;component/Images/a.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

What does that ";" do in this Uri string?

That a.png is actually under MyProgramName/Images/a.png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a delimeter for one of the variations of [WPF Resource URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). Semicolon does not hold any specific universal meaning for all URIs.